# Recognizing handwritten shapes

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, image-processing

I want to recognize handwriting shape and figure out which shape it probably is in the set. Simply saying, if I draw a triangle, the application should recognize it as an triangle.
How can I do this using C# or java, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

These are some of the shapes I need to identify
[image]

Comment: Could you post examples (screenshots) of the shapes?

Comment: I have added some screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for that. [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a good wrapper to OpenCV for .net. Watch for ShapeDetection demo (included in OpenCV)

Comment: Download EmguCV binaries/sources. Demo apps (both binaries and sources) are shipped with the library.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "roll your own"  I would suggest the following steps:

First, skeletonize (thin out the image till all the lines are one pixel thick).  There are many ways to do this, and it is a well studied problem.  Google for more information.

Now, starting at a black pixel, go through and trace out the outline of the image, one pixel at a time.  You add each of these segments to a list of segments outlining the shape (each segment will be a simple line from one pixel to its adjacent pixel).  Now you have the outline of your shape as a many-sided polygon.

(Possible step at this point: smooth the outline by pulling each vertex closer to the average of its neighbors)

Now, you use a corner detection algorithm to find the corners (take a look here:http://visual.ipan.sztaki.hu/corner/node7.html).

This should be enough to identify the shapes you have listed.

If you want to get smarter, you can also identify the types of edges that exist between corners.  If the segment between two corners stays within some threshold of the straight line between them, you treat it as a "straight line" edge.  If it doesn't,  you treat it as a curving edge.

With corners +straight/curving edge, you probably could detect any of the shapes you are looking for pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a [neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network).

You could teach it what the shapes look like.

This is one library for example:

**[Neural Networks on C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for particular shapes inside a larger image then [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a great alternative. [Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a good .Net wrapper for it. See [my picture of a SURF implementation](http://blog.tedd.no/2011/03/12/kinect-opencv-object-recognition/) for this. Also see [other options in OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvconvexitydefects#cvConvexityDefects), it has plenty to offer. Note that this approach requires a lot of processing power.

If you can easily identify the shape you want as a BLOB (that is, give the algorithm a picture of only this shape) you can do a search for "ANN OCR" ("Artificial Neural Networks" and "Optical Character Recognition"). Many (most?) ANN-implementations come with sample code for feeding it shapes (letters) and recognizing closest shape (hand written letters). For example [Neural Network OCR](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/neural_network_ocr.aspx). I believe this approach would solve your problem. (Sidenote: I've encountered and tested numerous libs that can do this. It's Neural Networks 101.)

If you need BLOB algorithms for the ANN-OCR OpenCV can provide this.

Both these approaches are farily easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a vast tree of research in shape recognition.
If your shapes are indeed some what predictable and are basic geometry,
the most straightforward way is to find the edges and apply hough transform.

Some managable reading materials for you to start with, 
[1] Google Scholar for Hough Transform Shape Detection
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=hough+transform+shape+recognition&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart
[2] Hough Transform @ Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform